# Fetching and specifying a merge strategy

Tags: git

I'll explain my problem and hopefully I can be advised on the best way to solve it

My git repository contains the following directories:

```
/directoryA
/directoryB
```

However `directoryB` is out of synch with the remote branch. All the files on the remote branch have a ^M on each line, so there is a conflict on each and every line.

What I'm trying to do is to pull from the remote and for any conflicts **in this directory** use what is on the remote branch as the "correct" version.

However, when I performed a fetch it seemed to download the files and create the conflicts without me specifying an option to merge.

How can I specify to the use the remote as the "correct" version as part of the git fetch?

Comment: Minor but important git terminology quirk: "fetch" means "get stuff into my `.git` repo from a remote" and is entirely independent of working-directory items.  The step you're concerned with is the "merge" part of the operation.  If you're using "git pull", be aware that this is really two separate things: "fetch" (where your working directory is irrelevant), followed by "merge" (where working directory matters, but so do commits).

Comment: Is it important that only directoryB should get merged using the remote versions?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think the mistake I made was that I performed git fetch origin <branch_name> and this seemed to also do a merge. If I left out the <branch_name> it didn't seem to do the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually merge only one directory. You'd have to do workaround with a patch but since you want only remote version of directory this should do the trick (assuming you already run `git fetch`):

`git checkout <remote>/<branch> /directoryB`

This won't do any commits though so remember you will have to commit the changes. After that you should be able to do merge without any conflicts.

If you are in the middle of the merge though you can just do `git checkout --theirs /directoryB` and finish the merge